# flutter build apk file not working on http requests?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I used the command `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` then the app size got reduced from 48Mb to 7.1Mb.
But in this reduced apk, the HTTP requests are not working.
I also built using `flutter build apk`, through this the app size reduced to 19Mb, In this also the requests are not working.
So what to do to reduce the application size and make the app work perfectly.

Comment: I suggest checking the Logs in your build to check for any Network errors from the failed HTTP requests. We can't really guess here if we don't have Logs that we can check.

Comment: If your requests are working properly in debug mode it might be because you did not add internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @TesteurManiak
As you said I added the internet permission tag in manifest.xml file. Now it is working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Testeur Maniak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9942346/testeur-maniak) said to add the internet permission tag in the manifest.xml file, in the above comments.
I tried by adding the line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

If doing the above but still not working.
Try changing your endpoints url from "HTTP" to "HTTPS".
example;

If it was " [http://mylink.com/api"](http://mylink.com/api%22)
Change it to "https://mylink.com/api"